# My N-body program runs 100x slower when coded in Julia vs. when coded in C, why?

Tags: c, optimization, julia

I was writing a direct nbody routine in julia, and portability issues made me rewrite it in C. After writing it, I was surprised by the speedup, I was expecting even an order of magnitude but not two!

I was wondering if it's normal such an speedup with only a rewriting in C, being Julia so focused on speed and HPC.

This are the codes, I have simplified them to make them concise preserving the speedup of C (all masses are 1, Force is just the distance of the two bodies).

The loop iterates over every index (The star propierties array is fixed size, but I only use the first 400 for the test) and computes the contribution of the rest of the indexes, then uses an Euler integrator to compute the new position (new velocity += F/m times dt, new position += velocity times dt).

C code, compiled with `gcc` and no special flags, `time ./a.out` gives 0.98s:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Array of stars is fixed size. It's initialized to a maximum size
// and only the needed portion it's used.
#define MAX_STAR_N (int)5e5

double *x,*y,*z,*vx,*vy,*vz;    

void evolve_bruteforce(double dt){
    // Compute forces and integrate the system with an Euler
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<400;i++){
        double cacheforce[3] = {0,0,0};
        double thisforce[3];
        for(j=0;j<400;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                thisforce[0] = (x[j] - x[i]);
                thisforce[1] = (y[j] - y[i]);
                thisforce[2] = (z[j] - z[i]);
                cacheforce[0] += thisforce[0];
                cacheforce[1] += thisforce[1];
                cacheforce[2] += thisforce[2];
            }
         }
        vx[i] += cacheforce[0]*dt;
        vy[i] += cacheforce[1]*dt;
        vz[i] += cacheforce[2]*dt;
    }
    for(i=0;i<400;i++){
       x[i] += vx[i]*dt;
       y[i] += vy[i]*dt;
       z[i] += vz[i]*dt;
    }
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    // Malloc all the arrays needed
    x   = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAX_STAR_N);
    y   = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAX_STAR_N);
    z   = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAX_STAR_N);
    vx  = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAX_STAR_N);
    vy  = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAX_STAR_N);
    vz  = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAX_STAR_N);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        evolve_bruteforce(0.001);
    }
}
```

Julia code, executed with `julia -O --check-bounds=no`, gives 102 seconds:

```
function evolve_bruteforce(dt,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz)
    for i in 1:400
        cacheforce = [0.0,0.0,0.0]
        thisforce = Vector{Float64}(3)
        for j in 1:400
            if i != j
                thisforce[1] = (x[j] - x[i])
                thisforce[2] = (y[j] - y[i])
                thisforce[3] = (z[j] - z[i])
                cacheforce[1] += thisforce[1]
                cacheforce[2] += thisforce[2]
                cacheforce[3] += thisforce[3]
                vx[i] += cacheforce[1]*dt
                vy[i] += cacheforce[2]*dt
                vz[i] += cacheforce[3]*dt
            end
            for i in 1:400
                x[i] += vx[i]*dt
                y[i] += vy[i]*dt
                z[i] += vz[i]*dt
            end
        end
    end
end



function main()
    x = zeros(500000)
    y = zeros(500000)
    z = zeros(500000)
    vx = zeros(500000)
    vy = zeros(500000)
    vz = zeros(500000)
    @time for i in 1:1000
        evolve_bruteforce(0.001,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz)
    end
end

main()
```

I don't know how I can make this easier to answer out, if I can modify the post in any way please, let me know.

Comment: I don't know Julia, but the two examples above don't seem equivalent: the Julia function `evolve_brute` uses nested for loops into 3 levels, whereas the C equivalent only use 2 levels.

Comment: The indentation in the Julia code appears to be wrong. It looks like you've got an `i` loop that contains a `j` loop which contains an `i` loop. The C code on the other hand, has an `i` loop that contains a `j` loop, and the second `i` loop is *after*, not inside, the first `i` loop.

Comment: To get the most you can out of your C code, compile with the `-Ofast` optimization option if using `gcc >= 4.6`, or `-O3` if using earlier versions. I don't know julia, but speedups of this order are not uncommon going from scripted languages (or quasi script languages). If julia is a compiled language, then it would be hard to believe there would be that much of a difference in something that is basically a set of nested loops.

Comment: Julia did have as its `1st` performance tip - *Never use (non-constant) global variables.* I don't know if that applies here, but that could be another reason.

Comment: You can find an optimized version of the n-body code here https://github.com/KristofferC/BenchmarksGame.jl
Now it's much faster.

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out in the comments, the julia code is not equivalent to the C code. In the julia code the second `for i in 1:400` is inside instead of after the first for loop.  The code inside the if statement is also not the same.

Below is a version of `evolve_bruteforce` that matches the C code better:

```
function evolve_bruteforce(dt,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz)
    for i in 1:400
        cacheforce = [0.0,0.0,0.0]
        thisforce = Vector{Float64}(3)
        for j in 1:400
            if i != j
                thisforce[1] = (x[j] - x[i])
                thisforce[2] = (y[j] - y[i])
                thisforce[3] = (z[j] - z[i])
                cacheforce[1] += thisforce[1]
                cacheforce[2] += thisforce[2]
                cacheforce[3] += thisforce[3]
            end
        end
        # this bit was inside the if statement
        vx[i] += cacheforce[1]*dt
        vy[i] += cacheforce[2]*dt
        vz[i] += cacheforce[3]*dt
    end
    # this loop was nested inside the first one
    for i in 1:400
        x[i] += vx[i]*dt
        y[i] += vy[i]*dt
        z[i] += vz[i]*dt
    end
end
```

---

It should be noted that the **benchmarks in this answer are quite naïve and potentially unfair**, there are a lot of different language- and compiler specific optimization that can be used boost performance.

The Julia code above gives execution times of roughly 2.2 and 1.7 seconds:

```
# without any flags
2.188550 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 61.035 MB, 0.19% gc time)
2.199045 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 61.035 MB, 0.15% gc time)
2.194662 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 61.035 MB, 0.15% gc time)
# using the flags in the question: julia -O --check-bounds=on
1.688692 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 61.035 MB, 0.19% gc time)
1.705764 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 61.035 MB, 0.19% gc time)
1.688692 seconds (800.00 k allocations: 61.035 MB, 0.19% gc time)
```

On the same laptop the execution times for the C code in posted in the question are roughly 1.6 and 0.6 seconds:

```
# gcc without any flags
1.568s
1.585s
1.592s
# using gcc -Ofast
0.620s
0.594s
0.568s
```

Answer (score 9):

When using hard-coded 3 dimensional code, using `Tuple` type instead of `Array` is more appropriate (there will be no appending of additional physical dimensions in the middle of the simulation - even when doing superstring theory).

Rewriting @jarmokivekas's `evolve_bruteforce` like this:

```
function evolve_bruteforce(dt,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz)
    for i in 1:400
        cacheforce = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
        thisforce = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
        for j in 1:400
            if i != j
                thisforce = ((x[j] - x[i]),(y[j] - y[i]),(z[j] - z[i]))
                cacheforce = (cacheforce[1]+thisforce[1],
                              cacheforce[2]+thisforce[2],
                              cacheforce[3]+thisforce[3])
            end
        end
        # this bit was inside the if statement
        (vx[i],vy[i],vz[i]) = (vx[i]+cacheforce[1]*dt,
                               vy[i]+cacheforce[2]*dt,
                               vz[i]+cacheforce[3]*dt)
    end
    # this loop was nested inside the first one
    for i in 1:400
         (x[i],y[i],z[i]) = (x[i]+vx[i]*dt,y[i]+vy[i]*dt,z[i]+vz[i]*dt)
    end
end
```

This gives another **2x speedup** (from 1.1sec to 0.5sec on this machine).

Comment: Now, `thisforce` should not really be defined outside the `j` loop.

Comment: The `if i != j` is redundant, as `x[j]-x[i]` is zero and leaves `cacheforce` unchanged. Removing `if ... end` gives another 10% speedup (getting rid of conditionals is a standard optimization trick)

Comment: Adding `@simd` in front of inner `for j in 1:400` gives (appropriately CPUed machines) another >10% speedup.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating language specific quirks of data types. This implementation executes in 0.7 seconds, compared to the 1.7 seconds of the Julia benchmark in my own answer, and the 1.6 and 0.6 seconds of the C implementation.

Comment: Removing the `if ... end` and using `@simd` as @user3580870 suggests dropped the execution time down to 0.2 seconds on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer comes with the advent of Julia 0.7-alpha release. Also, I didn't observe that another answer is very close to mine unless after posting this.

---

The "julian" way of dealing with short vectors is using `SVector`s or simply `tuple`s. Using two tuples for `cacheforce` and `thisforce` and compiling with `-O3` yields a julia version that is faster than C.

```
function evolve_bruteforce(dt,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz)

    @inbounds for i in 1:400
        cacheforce =  (0.0,0.0,0.0)
        thisforce  =  (0.0,0.0,0.0) 
        for j in 1:400
            if i != j
                thisforce  = (x[j] - x[i],
                              y[j] - y[i],
                              z[j] - z[i])
                cacheforce = (thisforce[1]+cacheforce[1],
                              thisforce[2]+cacheforce[2],
                              thisforce[3]+cacheforce[3])
            end
        end
        # this bit was inside the if statement
        vx[i] += cacheforce[1]*dt
        vy[i] += cacheforce[2]*dt
        vz[i] += cacheforce[3]*dt
    end
    # this loop was nested inside the first one
    @inbounds for i in 1:400
        x[i] += vx[i]*dt
        y[i] += vy[i]*dt
        z[i] += vz[i]*dt
    end
end

function main()
    x = Array{Float64}(undef,500000)
    y = Array{Float64}(undef,500000)
    z = Array{Float64}(undef,500000)
    vx = Array{Float64}(undef,500000)
    vy = Array{Float64}(undef,500000)
    vz = Array{Float64}(undef,500000)
    @time for i in 1:1000
        evolve_bruteforce(0.001,x,y,z,vx,vy,vz)
    end
end

main()
```

And the timing is impressive:

```
# using julia -O3 main.jl
  0.223773 seconds
# using gcc -Ofast
  Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.249 s
```